# Can't import gorilla/mux (github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.7.4: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt)

Tags: go, gorilla, pq

In Go, I was trying simple database connection. I need to import `gorilla/mux`, but I couldn't.

I am using VS Code. After `cd` ing to my project directory, I created `main.go` and did run 
`go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux`

Here is **main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 3000
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "postgres"
    dbname   = "test1"
)

func main() {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected!")
}
```

[Note that,  after executing `go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux` terminal shows

```
C:\Go\src\github.com\IamFrost\go-rest-api>go get -v -u github.com/gorilla/mux
go: golang.org/x/text upgrade => v0.3.2
go: golang.org/x/crypto upgrade => v0.0.0-20200429183012-4b2356b1ed79
go: golang.org/x/sys upgrade => v0.0.0-20200430082407-1f5687305801
go: golang.org/x/net upgrade => v0.0.0-20200425230154-ff2c4b7c35a0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200430082407-1f5687305801
golang.org/x/sys/cpu
golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305
crypto/tls
```

]

[image]
Look i have no other syntax error in mini map. At red mark, when I put mouse, the hover text, its funny to me:

1)`imported but not used`

but the next line

2)`no package for import github.com/gorilla/mux`)

lol didn't that go against 1) ?

Someone please explain why that occurs

However,

After using `go build` in **terminal**

Here is terminal:

```
C:\Go\src\github.com\IamFrost\go-rest-api>go build
go: inconsistent vendoring in C:\Go\src:
        github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.7.4: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        github.com/lib/pq@v1.4.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20200429183012-4b2356b1ed79: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        golang.org/x/net@v0.0.0-20200425230154-ff2c4b7c35a0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200430082407-1f5687305801: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20200128174031-69ecbb4d6d5d: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
        golang.org/x/net@v0.0.0-20191126235420-ef20fe5d7933: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
        golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200201011859-915c9c3d4ccf: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod

run 'go mod vendor' to sync, or use -mod=mod or -mod=readonly to ignore the vendor directory
```

[Note : I did 'go mod vendor' also, but no change]

So someone point me why I can't import `gorilla/mux` or `pq`.

What else I have to do?

(and please explain what does that mean? `is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt`)

Comment: You can either vendor your dependencies or not vendor them but your current state uses vendored packages and the unvendored gorilla/mux and that is the error message telling you. Re-vendor everything.

Comment: @Volker how to do that? Any example or suggestion?

Comment: `go mod vendor`?

Comment: @Volker i did, but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it works (I am beginner). I found something in net, somehow it worked .
Here is how :

1. This is my go directory `C:\Go\` . But I create the project in my desktop folder
2. Then I recreated the project under `C:\Go\src`
   (this is exact folder
   `C:\Go\src\github.com\[github_username]\[project_name]` )
3. Then I pasted all the code at `main.go`
4. Finally from terminal `go mod vendor`
5. Then `go build`
6. Then `go run main.go`
7. Finally it worked

[I would like to know why it worked. I would really appreciate your comment : about why they are forcing me to go under `C:\Go\src`. I already have **GOPATH** `C:\Go\` , **GOBIN** `C:\Go\bin` set in environment variable]

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I fixed it for me:

```
go get ./...
go mod tidy
```

If your Go version is less than `1.13` then, you should prepend `GO111MODULE=on`  in above commands.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent releases of Golang (1.11 onwards I think) there's been a change on the GOPATH variable.  My understanding is you only need to set this if GOPATH will not be $HOME/go.

Go looks for your projects in $HOME/go/src/, for instance my Golang projects are in $Home/go/src/github.com/<your_github_userid>` directory, etc.

If you want to use a different location of your projects, you can still set the GOPATH to a different directory.

And my shell file has the following to accommodate both a set and not set GOPATH.

export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"

You can get more information at the [GOPATH environment documentation](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html#GOPATH)

Answer (score 0):

go mod init ,
go mod tidy ,
go run :3

I working in default directory (C:\Go\src[projectName]) and run commands in project directory. If is not help u , move project to your GOPATH